# Qt: no playback on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, audio

I have tried (I think) every possible way of playing audio in a Qt project, none of which have worked:

- `QSound::play(...)`
- QMediaPlayer
- QAudioOutput, from http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaudiooutput.html

None of these solutions play WAV or MP3, and I have tried loading the files from a resource (`qrc:media/file.wav`) or simply from disk (`/full/path/to/file.wav`).

I think the problem is with codecs. `QAudioDevice::supportedCodecs()` returns an empty list. I'm on a linux system that has no problems playing audio/video (Ubuntu 14.04, usually playing in VLC... that uses its own codecs?).

Playing with QSound (WAV & MP3):

```
QSoundEffect(pulseaudio): Error decoding source
```

QMediaplayer (WAV): nothing happens

QMediaplayer (MP3):

```
GStreamer; Unable to play - "qrc:media/lowtone.mp3"
```

Comment: QAudioDevice::supportedCodecs doesn't not even return `audio/pcm`?

Comment: @UmNyobe nope... size() of the QStringList returns 0

Answer (score 1):

Qt uses [specific media backends](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.4_Multimedia_Backends) for each platform(link is qt5, but it was the same in Qt4). From the error it looks like your version is using `GStreamer`.

Check if the gstreamer dev packages on your distribution are well installed, because `QAudioDevice::supportedCodecs` [**must** return at least *audio/pcm*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#supportedCodecs). Work on the package setup until your test program show `pcm`. See https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_for_Linux

You may also need to install plugins (also dev packages) before being able to play wav or mp3 using phonon.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting `audio/pcm` now returned by `supportedCodecs`. I noticed that `QMediaPlayer::play` does work when called as a slot (by emitting a signal). Apparently it has to be called asynchronously to work properly, even if the object is allocated on the heap and lives beyond the scope of the caller. I still can't use `QSound::play` though... that one *is* supposed to block, right?